# Passage of a vector of structures to a function

Tags: c, function, graph, vector, struct

My program is working with graph, and I'm trying to create a vector of edges. The edge type in my program is this one :

```
typedef struct arco{
    TipoNodo p, s;
    int peso;
    }arco;
```

where p and s are the vertex, and peso is how much is long the edge.

I'm trying to create a vector of the edges made from the adjacency matrix, but when I pass the vector of type arco to my function, my program raises a run time error. How should I pass the vector of arcos to my function, and modify his elements?

main code:

```
case 'f':
      printf("Algoritmo di Dijkstra. Scrivere Nodo i di partenza: ");
      scanf("%d", &i);
      arco vet[MaxArchi];

          int dimensione;
          printf("fuck\n");
//I'm debugging just the matrix part, becouse I think that the error with adjacency list is the same.
          if(matlist=='m') dimensione = CodaMinPrioritaMatrice(grafoMat, vet); else dimensione = CodaMinPrioritaLista(grafoList, vet);
//printing the array, the program doesn't arrive here.
          for(peso = 0; peso <dimensione; peso++) printf("%d->%d, (%d)\n", vet[peso].p, vet[peso].s, vet[peso].peso);
          break;
```

function:

```
int CodaMinPrioritaMatrice(GrafoMatrice *grafo, arco *vet[]){
      int dimensione;
      TipoNodo i, j;
      for(i=0; i<NumNodi; i++)
          for(j = 0; j<NumNodi; j++)
              if(grafo->matr_adiacenza[i][j] != 0){
                                             //the program stops here
                     //*vet[dimensione] = malloc(sizeof(arco));
                     vet[dimensione].p = i;
                     vet[dimensione].s = j;
                     vet[dimensione].peso = grafo->matr_adiacenza[i][j];

                     dimensione++;                    
              }
      return dimensione;
}
```

I don't post my whole program because I wrote more or less 600 lines of code, all I know about graph

Thank you every body

Giacomo.

Comment: You're passing it as a value: instead pass it as a reference with: CodaMinPrioritaMatrice(grafoMat, &vet)

Comment: @M You probably meant "pass a pointer to it". There's no pass by reference in C.

Comment: I think thet vector are pass as pointer.. also without '&'. i.e. if I modify a value in a vector in a function this value is modofied in the main too, also if I pass the vector without the '&'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make one more change in your code...

```
int dimensione=0;
```

you are using a variable without initialization.

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your code -

Change the function definition from:

```
int CodaMinPrioritaMatrice(GrafoMatrice *grafo, arco *vet[]){
```

To:

```
int CodaMinPrioritaMatrice(GrafoMatrice *grafo, arco *vet){
```